# Sample variance equation not producing right estimate of population variance?

Tags: variance

Given a population of `[7, 14, 21, 28]`, I am sampling two data points at a time, calculating the (unbiased) sample variance, averaging the results, and expecting the mean of the results to be an estimate of the population's variance (`61.25`). But I'm not getting the right answer:

There are 6 equi-probable samples of two data points:

| sample | sample variance | population variance of sample |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [7, 14] | 24.5 | 12.25 |
| [7, 21] | 98.0 | 49.0 |
| [7, 28] | 220.5 | 110.25 |
| [14, 21] | 24.5 | 12.25 |
| [14, 28] | 98.0 | 49.0 |
| [21, 28] | 24.5 | 12.25 |
| / | mean = 81.67 | mean=40.833 --> multiply that by 3/2 = 61.25 |

Why isn't the mean of the sample variances equal to the population variance `61.25`? And why if I multiply the mean population variance of each sample by 3/2 I get the right population variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2-element samples are *without replacement*. Bessel-corrected sample variance will be unbiased for samples *with replacement*, that is, you should be choosing two elements $x_1$ and $x_2$ independently from the population.

Most importantly, you are missing the samples $[7,7], [14,14], [21,21], [28,28]$. They would have sample variance $0$. Since you are missing these zeros, your average sample variance is too large.

Include them, and also include the samples where $x_1>x_2$ (like $[14,7]$), and behold, your average sample variance is $61.25$.

As to the magnitude of the error: With replacement you have $16$ different samples. You were missing the $4$ that have zero sample variance. (You were also not considering the $x_1>x_2$ samples, but that does not matter here because of symmetry.) So you were overestimating the population variance by a factor of $16/12 = 4/3$. This checks out: your $81\frac{2}{3}$ is $(4/3) \times 61.25$.

As to the "population variances" (really: uncorrected sample variances) in the rightmost column: They have an additional bias (yes, the well-known bias of uncorrected sample variances), indeed they are too small by a factor of $(n-1)/n = 1/2$, where $n=2$ is the sample size. Compounding these *two* errors, their average is wrong by a factor of $(4/3) \cdot (1/2) = 2/3$. Which explains why multiplying by $3/2$ fixes both errors.